# Replace word bookmark text with vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am following this websites method https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/word/bookmarks of using the existing bookmark range to change text and reinsert. However I get a type mismatch error when I try to set the range for my existing bookmarks. When I hover over StartDate in VBE it says 'Nothing'. I have tried it with wdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks rather than GIR.Bookmarks as well and get the same issue. Any ideas? Thanks

```
Sub GIToWord()
'
' Select GI Summary data in excel and copy to GIR
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim GIR As Word.Document
    Dim GIRName As String
    Dim Start As Date
    Dim Finish As Date
    Dim iNum As Integer
    Dim iMax As Integer
    Dim First As Date
    Dim Last As Date
    Dim StartDate As Range
    Dim EndDate As Range
    Dim NumLocations As Range
    Dim MaxDepth As Range
    Dim FirstRound As Range
    Dim LastRound As Range
                    
Set wdApp = New Word.Application '<<<  Create a Word application object
wdApp.Visible = True '<<<< Open word so you can see any errors
    
GIRName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose GIR to open", _
                                          FileFilter:="Word Files *.docm* (*.docm*),")
Set GIR = wdApp.Documents.Open(GIRName) '<< call Documents.Open on the word app
    
    'Assign data to variables
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Start = ws.Cells(2, 5)
    Finish = ws.Cells(2, 6)
    iNum = ws.Cells(2, 1)
    iMax = ws.Cells(2, 4)
    First = ws.Cells(11, 35)
    Last = ws.Cells(11, 36)
    
           
            'Paste data into word at associated bookmarks and recreate
            Set StartDate = GIR.Bookmarks("StartDate").Range
            StartDate.Text = Start
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "StartDate", StartDate
            
            Set EndDate = GIR.Bookmarks("EndDate").Range
            EndDate.Text = Finish
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "EndDate", EndDate
                        
            Set NumLocations = GIR.Bookmarks("NumLocations").Range
            NumLocations.Text = iNum
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "NumLocations", NumLocations
            
            Set MaxDepth = GIR.Bookmarks("MaxDepth").Range
            MaxDepth.Text = iMax
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "MaxDepth", MaxDepth
            
            Set FirstRound = GIR.Bookmarks("FirstRound").Range
            FirstRound.Text = First
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "FirstRound", FirstRound
            
            Set LastRound = GIR.Bookmarks("LastRound").Range
            LastRound.Text = Last
            GIR.Bookmarks.Add "LastRound", LastRound

    GIR.Save
    
    
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Declaring a variable `As Range` when run in Excel will refer to an Excel `Range` object type, not the Word range you want `Dim AAAA As Word.Range` will avoid the confusion.

Comment: You can also consider factoring out the code which replaces the bookmark text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765204/updating-bookmarks-in-word-with-vba/45765527#45765527

Comment: That's great thanks @Tim Williams